# On an Apple Keyboard under Linux, how do I make the Function keys work without the fn modifier key?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, apple

I use an Apple wired keyboard on Linux. By default the function keys (F1, F2, F3, etc) require the `fn` key to be pressed for them to work. Without the `fn` key, these keys control the features like Screen Brightness, Volume, and Music Track Control.

Is there any way to swap these around, so the Function keys do not require the `fn` modifier, but the other functions (Brightness etc) do?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to add `0` or `2` into `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`.

i.e.:

```
echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

There seems to be some confusion regarding what the difference between the two values might be. Quoting the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior):

> 1. 0 = disabled : Disable the 'fn' key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave
>    like you only press 'F8'
> 2. 1 = fkeyslast : Function keys are used as
>    last key. Pressing 'F8' key will act as a special key. Pressing
>    'fn'+'F8' will behave like a F8.
> 3. 2 = fkeysfirst : Function keys are
>    used as first key. Pressing 'F8' key will behave like a F8. Pressing
>    'fn'+'F8' will act as special key (play/pause).

Note that this also works for me on Fedora.

---

As several people have commented, this change is temporary. You can stick it in your login shell's RC file or into cron so that you don't have to worry about it.

You can also change your driver settings to make this change permanent, like so:

```
echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
# reboot when convenient
```

credits to https://askubuntu.com/a/7553

Comment: it's fnmode = no underscore

Comment: This also works with the M87 keyboard from "velocifire".  It is a budget mechanical keyboard but thank you so much for the fix, shows up as an Apple USB device so the apple_hid parameter fix worked for it as well!! So happy can use this kb now.

Comment: in some systems need 2 in quote:  echo "2"> /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode and well done.

Comment: To make this change permanent (after reboot, the value was reset automatically for me), see https://askubuntu.com/a/7553/197712

Comment: As @bikashg said, this change is not permanent and making it so should be part of this answer.

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly on a 2015 MacBook Air that I just upgraded with a new SSD and onto which I installed _dualboot_ **MacOS 12** (installed for free via the Mac "internet boot" option--see my comments at the bottom of [my website article here](https://gabrielstaples.com/repairing-macbook/#gsc.tab=0)) and Linux **Ubuntu 22.04.3**! I simply ran `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` and then added `options hid_apple fnmode=2` to the top of that file to get the desired effect. Then, `reboot`. Works perfectly! Upvoted.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone stumbling upon this thread using one of the newer MacBook Pros (2016 and later) which need the [applespi](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver) driver to make the keyboard and touchpad work, here's how to make this work, as I couldn't find any other thread explaining this for newer Macs.

As far as I understand, the driver effectively replaces the role of the hid_apple module, so the files to edit are slightly different.

First, to verify that you are using the applespi driver and not the hid_apple driver, check what this command returns (using the terminal). It will tell you which driver you are currently using:

```
# If this returns "applespi", you are using applespi
ls /sys/module | grep -e applespi -e hid_apple
```

To test settings *temporarily* (settings will be reset after a reboot):

```
echo 2 | sudo tee -a /sys/module/applespi/parameters/fnmode
```

To apply the changes *permanently* (persist with reboots):

```
# Add the option for the fn key
echo options applespi fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/applespi.conf
# Update initramfs bootfile
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
# Reboot to test (optional)
sudo reboot
```

For older MacBook Pros using the hid_apple module, use "hid_apple" rather than "applespi" in the commands.

Comment: This helped me out and worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that it is pretty simple to change the behaviour of this modifier,  As root change the value in the file `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` from `1` to `0`. For example:

# echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode

Note that in some older versions of linux, this file was located in `/sys/module/apple/parameters/fnmode`. Also, this change will not persist when you reboot.

Answer (score 2):

For those who get access denied and could not simply prefix "sudo" use:

```
sudo nano /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Change it to `2` or whatever and then `Ctrl+X` to save.

Comment: better way is to `echo 2| sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`, but all these solutions are transient  .... 


One way to make persistent (on `systemd` environments like Fedora for example) :  `echo "w /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode - - - - 2" | sudo tee /etc/tmpfiles.d/rev_fn_key.conf`

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I suggest update the Kernel configurations with the following command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

In an [older discussion](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-857617-start-0.html) a solution is given with a kernel boot parameter which might be preferable (system-wide application, modification of just a line in `/etc/default/grub`, etc).

Only according to that solution, `fnmode` is set to `2` instead of `0`. I just tried to set `hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` to `2`, and it has the desired effect too. Maybe the logic is simply `1 → "require <kbd>Fn</kbd> to access <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>,..." vs. all other values?

Comment: Hi RJVB, welcome to unix.SE.  I've edited your answer to improve the formatting.  Take a look at the source to learn some of the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@ffledgling's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156629/300994):

I suggest the following in order to make this setting being applied on every reboot (works fine on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and I think other distributions as well):

```
echo "options hid_apple fnmode=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
```