# Run sudo command on ubuntu startup without interaction (no need to provide password)?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, startup

Each time I start Ubuntu (20.04) I always need to start a terminal and run:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Since its for some reason not possible to configure Function Keys behavior permanently in the system setting (See
[On an Apple Keyboard under Linux, how do I make the Function keys work without the fn modifier key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121395/on-an-apple-keyboard-under-linux-how-do-i-make-the-function-keys-work-without-t))

But can I at least add the above command to some init script that will be executed automatically each time Ubuntu starts even though it requires sudo/root permissions?

Comment: Hm why the down vote? Does not seem like a completely trivial question o that its  lacking details. Also based on the answers there is also some good knowledge to be shared it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command actually sets a parameter for the `hid_apple` kernel module.

If the module is not compiled into the kernel, you could just create a text file named `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` with the following contents:

```
options hid_apple fnmode=2
```

This is the standard way of setting module parameters persistently.

You could name the file anything you want, as long as you put it into `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory and the name has a `.conf` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following to root's cron (with `sudo crontab -e`):

```
@reboot echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

- Enable rc.local https://linuxmedium.com/how-to-enable-etc-rc-local-with-systemd-on-ubuntu-20-04/ and add this command to `/etc/rc.local`
- Create a systemd unit/service: there are multiple guides on the net how to do it.