# How to write in /sys after boot

Tags: sudo, cron, services

for my F- and fn-keys to work I need to run this command `echo 0 | tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` after every boot. So i wanted to start it with a crontab, but this somehow does not work and I don't know why.

So I opened the corntab file like this `sudo crontab -e` and added the following:

`@reboot /home/myuser/.config/autostart-scripts/startup.sh`

But as I said, this doesn't work. The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

I added this script to sudoers to be executable but still doesn't work.
`myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/myuser/.config/autostart-scripts/startup.sh`
So i tried writing a service.

The service starts the script which is nice, but since it needs sudo permissions I think it needs to be placed in `/etc/systemd/system/my.service`. But when this service is started, I think `/sys` isn't there just yet. So how can I either start this service as a user (keep in mind that there needs to be a `sudo` done) or as a cronjob or as a service when `/sys` is created?

Comment: I guess you need [unix.stackexchange.com/a/511262/332764](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511262/332764) using `fnmode=0` and `hid_apple` instead of `applespi`, also described in [askubuntu.com/questions/7537/#7553](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7537/#7553)?

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me on manjaro