# Function Lock. can't disable

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, manjaro, lock

I'm using a Feker Machinist 01. On both Manjaro and Linux Mint (both running cinnamon), the function keys are "locked" to those silly laptop features like enabling/disabling wifi, adjusting volume, adjusting screen contrast etc. I don't want any of this nonsense, i just want the function keys to behave like function keys.

I note that this is not a problem on windows 10. On Win10 the Function keys behave as they should (eg F5 in firefox triggers a page refresh, rather than turning off my screen like it does on linux)

Answer (score 1):

(The question is different but it's the same answer as [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156629/41206))

You need to add 0 or 2 into /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode.

i.e.:

echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode

There seems to be some confusion regarding what the difference between the two values might be. Quoting the Ubuntu documentation:

```
    0 = disabled : Disable the 'fn' key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like you only press 'F8'
    1 = fkeyslast : Function keys are used as last key. Pressing 'F8' key will act as a special key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like a F8.
    2 = fkeysfirst : Function keys are used as first key. Pressing 'F8' key will behave like a F8. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will act as special key (play/pause).
```

Note that this also works for me on Fedora.